# Merge statement inserting instead of updating in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to load a new (target) table from a staging (source) table. The target table is empty.

I think since my target table is empty, the MERGE statement skips the WHEN MATCHED part i.e. result of INNER JOIN is NULL and so nothing is UPDATED, and it just proceed to the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET part (LEFT OUTER JOIN) an inserts all the records in the staging table.

My target table looks exactly similar to my staging table (rows #1 and #4). There should be only 3 rows in the target table (3 inserts and one update for row #4). So, I'm not sure whats going on.

```
FileID  client_id account_name  account_currency  creation_date last_modified
210     12345           Cars            USD       2013-11-21    2013-11-27 
211     23498           Truck           USD       2013-09-22    2013-11-27 
212     97652           Cars - 1        USD       2013-09-17    2013-11-27 
210     12345           Cars            JPY       2013-11-21    2013-11-29
```

**QUERY**

```
MERGE [AccountSettings] AS tgt -- RIGHT TABLE
USING
(
SELECT * FROM [AccountSettings_Staging]
) AS src -- LEFT TABLE
ON src.client_id = tgt.client_id
AND src.account_name = tgt.account_name
WHEN MATCHED -- INNER JOIN
    THEN UPDATE
       SET
         tgt.[FileID] = src.[FileID]
        ,tgt.[account_currency] = src.[account_currency]
        ,tgt.[creation_date] = src.[creation_date]
        ,tgt.[last_modified] = src.[last_modified]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  -- left outer join: A row from the source that has no corresponding row in the target
THEN INSERT
    (
        [FileID],   
        [client_id], 
        [account_name],
        [account_currency],
        [creation_date], 
        [last_modified] 
    )
    VALUES
    (
        src.[FileID],   
        src.[client_id], 
        src.[account_name],
        src.[account_currency], 
        src.[creation_date], 
        src.[last_modified]             
    );
```

Comment: Related: [Stop using `MERGE` in the first place](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks. What do you suggest to use in its place other than IF EXISTS?

Comment: its empty for now but won't be for future runs of the job. If the MERGE statement keeps on inserting dupes for any accounts it leads to a problem.

Comment: you should say that in the question. Everything in the question leads me to believe this is some kind of one-time thing, or that the target table is always cleared first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the target table is empty, using `MERGE` seems to me like hiring a plumber to pour you a glass of water. And `MERGE` operates only one branch, independently, for every row of a table - it can't see that the key is repeated and so perform an insert and then an update - this betrays that you think SQL always operates on a row-by-row basis, when in fact most operations are performed on the entire set at once.

Why not just insert only the most recent row:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT FileID, ... other columns ..., 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY last_modified DESC)
  FROM dbo.AccountSettings_Staging
)
INSERT dbo.AccountSettings(FileID, ... other columns ...)
  SELECT FileID, ... other columns ...
  FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you have potential for ties on the most recent `last_modified`, you'll need to find another tie-breaker (not obvious from your sample data).

For future versions, I would say run an `UPDATE` first:

```
UPDATE a SET client_id = s.client_id /* , other columns that can change */
  FROM dbo.AccountSettings AS a
  INNER JOIN dbo.AccountSettings_Staging AS s
  ON a.FileID = s.FileID;
```

(Of course, this will choose an arbitrary row if the source contains multiple rows with the same `FileID` - you may want to use a CTE here too to make the choice predictable.)

Then add this clause to the `INSERT` CTE above:

```
FROM dbo.AccountSettings_Staging AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AccountSettings 
  WHERE FileID = s.FileID);
```

Wrap it all in a transaction at the appropriate isolation level, and you are still avoiding a ton of complicated `MERGE` syntax, potential bugs, etc.

Comment: its empty for now but won't be for future runs of the job. If the MERGE statement keeps on inserting dupes for any accounts it leads to a problem. Maybe I need to use the CTE as a SOURCE in the MERGE and then UPDATE or DELETE in the target table.

Comment: @Chang it will only insert dupes _if the source contains dupes that aren't in the target_.  I would also not trust SQL to update the records in the order that they appear in the CTE.  You'll need to address the dupes in the source either way (or use a cursor, which would be a last resort)

Comment: Aaron - isn't the `UPDATE`/`INSERT` what `MERGE` does behind-the-scenes anyways?  Not disputing your answer just reiterating that there's not a lot of "magic" with `MERGE`

Comment: @DStanley It sure is, so why use completely cumbersome and unintuitive syntax? Or go to the effort of validating that you aren't subject to about a dozen wrong results and other serious bugs that have yet to be fixed? Did you [read this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did and I agree absolutely - I was just reiterating that `MERGE` doesn't buy you much over an `UPDATE`/`INSERT` batch (+1 BTW)

Comment: @DStanley oh I see, I thought you were saying that there's no value in changing `MERGE` to `UPDATE/INSERT`, and that I disagree with. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I think since my target table is empty, the MERGE statement skips the WHEN MATCHED part

Well, that's correct, but it's by design - `MERGE` is not a "progressive" merge.  It does not go row-by-row to see if records inserted as part of the `MERGE` should now be updated.  It processes the source in "batches"  based on whether or not a match was found in the destination.

You'll need to deal with the "duplicate" records at the source before attempting the `MERGE`.